# ngx-quill with formula issue

Tags: quill

I added a formula to `ngx-quill`

```
  modules = {

toolbar: [      
  [{ header: [1, 2, false] }],
  ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
  ['formula'], 
  ['image', 'code-block']
]
   };
```

When entering a formula, it displays 2 times in the editor

[here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-quill-editor?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) is a reference link to the issue .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix for that by adding the right library in index.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).